# Write createWriteStream txt contents to a global variable with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, es6-promise, fs

I am trying to download txt and mp3 files and use the content of them in another node module.

How can I create a global variable with the piped contents from the downloaded txt (and MP3 at a later stage) file to use outside of the FTP function?

```
async function example() {
    var finalData = '';

    const client = new ftp.Client()
    client.ftp.verbose = true
    try {
    await client.access({
        host: "XXXX",
        user: "XXXX",
        password: "XXXX",
    })


    await client.upload(fs.createReadStream("README.txt"), myFileNameWithExtension)
    //let writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/' + myFileNameWithExtension);
    //await client.download(writeStream, myFileNameWithExtension)

    finalData = await (() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        writeStream
            .on('finish', () => {

            // Create a global variable to  be used outside of the FTP function scope to pipe the txt content into another node mogule

            })
            .on('error', (err) => {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
            })
        })
    })();
    }
    catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    }
    client.close();
    return finalData;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't create any global variables. Just resolve the promise with the data:

```
var finalData = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    writeStream.on('finish', () => {
        resolve(); // pass a value
    }).on('error', (err) => {
        reject(err);
    });
});
```

The `finalData` will become whatever value you pass into `resolve(…)` - I don't know what result you want to pass there. In the end, just return the data from your `example` function (as you already do), so that the caller will be able to use it after waiting for the returned promise.

Comment: So it would be something like ```writeStream.on('finish', () => {
        resolve(myFileNameWithExtension.toString('utf-8'));``` to pass the contents of a txt file?

Comment: That's passing the *name* of the file, not the contents, but yes something like that.

Comment: How can I reference the contents please?

Comment: You'd need to read the file… but if you are actually looking for the contents, maybe you shouldn't have written the stream into a file in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for you help, I;ll explore the following which looks like it may fit```.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/users/log.txt'));```